# How Can I Make a conditional with return in a .map without get out of main function?

Tags: javascript

My objective is create this object:

```js
{
  name: string,
  birthday: date
}
```

by this array:

```js
const dataArray = [
 {
  "id": "name",
  "type": "string"
 },
 {
  "id": "birthday",
  "type": "date"
 }
]
```

So, I create a .map of the array, like this:

```js
const inputsValues = {};

dataArray.map(item => {
  if(item.type === "date"){
    inputsValues[item.id] = new Date(item.value);
    return; // this line is the problem
  }

  inputsValues[item.id] = item.value;
});
```

Is there a option to make a return in this function without use `else`?

Comment: `map` is for creating a new array based off of the one being mapped over. Seems you want either `forEach` or  `reduce`. Also you can use a return there what makes you believe you cant? A `return` there doesnt leave the main function it just ends that particular call of the callback function

Comment: Seems like a good use case for `.filter`

Comment: However I need use item.id with a variable name, so I must create a object to use `e.[item.id]` because there is not $$variable like php.

Comment: I think i was misunderstanding what you were trying to do. `reduce` is probably the better option here.

Comment: If you're getting type errors as your comments to answers suggest, please change the tag to [tag:typescript] and update the question with the errors you're receiving so proper answers can be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using map only to loop on an array, without using the returned array, is an anti pattern. The function map creates a new array by applying the given callback to all the values of an array ie **dataArray**. This is not your case because you want an object at the end, not an array.

Tu build your structure you should use, instead, a **for of** loop, a **forEach** or **Array.reduce()**.

In case you just need to reduce your array to one single object, [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is the best option:

```js
const dataArray = [
    {
        "id": "name",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "id": "birthday",
        "type": "date"
    }
];

const obj = dataArray.reduce((carry, { id, type, value = '' }) => {
    carry[id] = type === 'date' ? new Date() : value;

    return carry;
}, {}); // remember to initialize your carry, see reduce doc.

console.log(obj); // My reduced object { name: '', date: 2022-...}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [
  {id: "name", type: "string", value: "John"},
  {id: "birthday", type: "date", value: "02.02.22"},
  {id: "holiday", type: "date", value: "03.03.33"}
]

const inputsValues = data
  // the "return" function - filters all non "date" items
  .filter(item => item.type != "date")
  // the map + inputsValue combination in one function
  .reduce((values, item) => ({[item.id]: item.value, ...values}), {})
  
console.log(inputsValues)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dataArray = [{
    "id": "name",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "id": "birthday",
    "type": "date"
  }

]
console.log(
  dataArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.id] = curr.type;
    return acc;
  }, {})
);
```

Comment: Apper this error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)` on line `acc[curr.id] = curr.type;`

Comment: You didn't mention anything about typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```js
const dataArray = [
 { "id": "name", "type": "string" },
 { "id": "birthday", "type": "date" }
]

console.log(dataArray.reduce((acc, obj, i) => {
  const key = obj.id;
  const value = obj.type;
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {}))
```

Comment: Apper this error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)` on line `acc[key] = value;`

Comment: You didn't say anything about typescript in your question